# Save image in C

Tags: c

I'm just learning C language, so I apologize in advanced if my question is not clear or if I'm asking the wrong question (or a dummy question).

I wrote a code in C that produces the fractal fern points and then plots them using openGL. 
My code is similar to the one found here (http://www.cs.csubak.edu/~marc/code/opengl/fern.c).

Now I want to save the image that I obtained to a file. I've been searching about this and most of the answers suggest to use a library for this, but I'd like to write my own function. I understand that the first step is to use glreadpixels to read the pixel, but I'm not sure what should be the next step.

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Decide what format do you want and read manuals for libjpeg, libpng, libtiff etc. Also if you want I can show my code for saving the same image in different formats.

Comment: I don't care about the format. It could be jpeg. I'm trying to do something like this http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/windowdump/windowdump.c .

Comment: You won't be able to read such "image". You'd better use libpng and write image to png file.

Comment: OK, I'm going to try that. Thanks for your help

Comment: xpm is one of the easiest image formats to implement

Comment: Write in [Netpbm format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) (simple plain text) and convert to JPG or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

libbmp is a very good choice.

http://code.google.com/p/libbmp/